# Slim error BadRouteException

Tags: php, slim

Verificando os logs no servidor encontrei o seguinte erro:

```
Slim Application Error:
Type: FastRoute\BadRouteException
Message: Static route "/client/schedules" is shadowed by previously defined variable route "/client/([^/]+)" for method "GET"
```

e ainda que tenha pesquisado realmente não ficou claro o que pode causar esse tipo de exceção.

Organização das rotas, caso seja relevante:

```
    #Client routes
    $app->get('/client[/{id}]', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});
    $app->post('/client', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});
    $app->delete('/client', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});

    #Credit routes
    $app->post('/credits/buy', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});

    #deliveryman routes
    $app->post('/deliveryman', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});

    #Moip routes
    $app->get('/teste', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args){});

    #Plan routes
    $app->get('/plans', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});
    $app->post('/plans', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});
    $app->post('/plans/sign', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});

    #Responses routes
    $app->get('/error', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});

    #Schedule routes
    $app->get('/schedule', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args ){});
    $app->post('/schedule/deny/{id}', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});
    $app->post('/schedule/cancel/{id}', function(Request $request,Response $response, $args){ });
    $app->post('/schedule/accept/{id}', function(Request $request,Response $response, $args){});
    $app->post('/schedule/accept', function(Request $request,Response $response, $args){});
    //client
    $app->post('/schedule', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args ){});

    #Users routes
    $app->get('/login/{type}', function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args) {});
    $app->get('/logout', function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args) {});
```

Comment: Você está acessando uma rota `/client/schedules` estaticamente, enquanto já há uma definição de rota dinâmica para `/client[/{id}]`.

Comment: aparentemente tinha uma rota duplicada, mas valeu =D

Comment: Se o meu comentário te ajudou a responder, eu monto uma resposta. Caso não, deixa a tua resposta de como resolveu o problema, pode ajudar outros no futuro.

Comment: Sim me desculpe, havia esquecido completamente do post, pois bem a solução foi a seguinte havia uma rota estática do tipo get sendo executada depois da rota dinâmica. Dessa forma só foi preciso reordenar, adicionando a rota estática antes da rota dinâmica.

Answer (score 1):

A solução para o problema foi reordenar as rotas, aparentemente meu erro foi devido a ordem das rotas no arquivo exemplo:

```
$app->post('/plans{id}', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});
$app->post('/plans/sign', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});
```

O Correto é

```
$app->post('/plans/sign', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});
$app->post('/plans{id}', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){});
```

Rota estática deve vir antes da dinâmica